# Calling a function in another file in VB Script

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am using a Test Driver script (testset Driver.vbs) in QTP and in it I am trying to call a function in another file.  I thought I could add this to the testset driver.vbs:

```
Function IncludeAOA
Dim objFSO, objFile, AR1

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\Server1\QTP Files\Community\Driver Scripts\AOAReg.vbs", 1)
    AR1 = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
    ExecuteGlobal AR1
End Function
```

I call the `IncludeAOA` function which seems to work.  But, when it gets to the `ExecuteGlobal AR1` line it fails with an

> Error: Invalid Character, Code: 800A0408.

Can anyone see what I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AR1 - i.e. the code in `AOAReg.vbs` - is to blame. Try to 'run' it with `cscript AOAReg.vbs`. If that does not show the error (including the line number), post the code or check the encoding of that file.

Comment: Since this was a test, I only put this in the AOAReg.vbs: 
Option Explicit
msgbox("loaded")

Comment: @JamesCraig - Then (a) reduce further: Just ' (comment); (b) check the encoding (utf8?, bom?); (c) dump/wscript.echo/msgbox AR1.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like the file was corrupted somehow.  I added the msgbox AR1 and got a couple funky characters back.  So, I renamed that file and created a new one from scratch.  This time it showed the text from the file!  Thanks again!